# Thread 1: break point error to send post method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to send post method (to login user) but when I click on login button in run time I got this message :

[image]

my class:

```
typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void

class RestApiManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = RestApiManager()

    let baseURL = "***********"


    func login(body: [String: AnyObject],onCompletion: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {
        let route = baseURL+"o/token/"
        makeHTTPPostRequest(path: route,body: body, onCompletion: { json, err in
            onCompletion(json as JSON)
        })
    }

    func getCategories(onCompletion: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {
        let route = baseURL+"o/token/"
        makeHTTPGetRequest(path: route, onCompletion: { json, err in
            onCompletion(json as JSON)
        })
    }

    func getRandomUser(onCompletion: @escaping (JSON) -> Void) {
        let route = baseURL
        makeHTTPGetRequest(path: route, onCompletion: { json, err in
            onCompletion(json as JSON)
        })
    }

    // MARK: Perform a GET Request
    private func makeHTTPGetRequest(path: String, onCompletion: @escaping ServiceResponse) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: path)! as URL)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            if let jsonData = data {
                let json:JSON = JSON(data: jsonData)
                onCompletion(json, error as NSError?)
            } else {
                onCompletion(nil, error as NSError?)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    // MARK: Perform a POST Request
    private func makeHTTPPostRequest(path: String, body: [String: AnyObject], onCompletion: @escaping ServiceResponse) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: path)! as URL)

        // Set the method to POST
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        do {
            // Set the POST body for the request
            let jsonBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .prettyPrinted)
            request.httpBody = jsonBody
            let session = URLSession.shared

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                if let jsonData = data {
                    let json:JSON = JSON(data: jsonData)
                    onCompletion(json, nil)
                } else {
                    onCompletion(nil, error as NSError?)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        } catch {
            // Create your personal error
            onCompletion(nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

in my login controller :

```
//after click on login button

let parameters = ["grant_type": "password",
                  "username": "test29@gmail.com",
                  "password": "1",
                  "client_id": "toS899lbMGolv8j24piz0JI38VUCi6Mvzru27iBA",
                  "client_secret":"lG14Tk7m2mGYLMvBndW2yFZ1NGRLNrriIPH6gw30gAnMAcFMa5xJE3wP8H 4SDHAK0ND5nKIoSLZskFQQ1knEYiaPC3i5LNutPJlusiMNiuvhUHWnbvTCjmNkuCBkGgqO"]




RestApiManager.sharedInstance.login(body: parameters as [String : AnyObject]) { (json: JSON) in

    print(json)

}
```

Comment: It is look like you have set the break point remove or disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it back to the main thread:

```
func login(body: [String: AnyObject],onCompletion:@escaping(JSON) -> Void) {
    let route = baseURL+"o/token/"
    makeHTTPPostRequest(path: route,body: body, onCompletion: { json, err in

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
            onCompletion(json as JSON)
        }
    })
}
```